# Creating scheduled email for every new leads

Tags: trigger, lightning-experience, process-builder

I have a business requirement to send email alert every Friday @ 9 AM after creating new leads. The problem is, I don't see any option where I can specify time or hours in Process Builder. I see option for number of days only.

Does anybody know if we can send email alerts at a specific time or not using Process Builder Flows?

Answer (score 0):

So, two options off the bat:

1. Do you want to distribute the list of leads to a group of people? If this is the case, maybe you want to do scheduled reports, where you can schedule the reports to run at a certain time and define the group of recipents. Here is somre more info: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_schedule_overview.htm&type=5
2. Do you want specific leads going to different people (i.e. every lead owner gets an email for each of thier leads? If this is the case, you can do a time based workflow, where you define the delay (number of hours/ days) and then send an email alert. Here is some docs on it: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1 . Here is an implementation of it : https://www.shellblack.com/administration/time-dependent/